# “Totally transitive” polytopes which are not regular

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, polytopes, abstract-polytopes

Is it possible to have an abstract polytope which is vertex-transitive, edge-transitive, face-transitive, etc. (individually transitive on faces of each particular dimension) and yet not flag-transitive?

[I had thought this might be an easy curiosity for Math StackExchange to readily answer for me, but I had no engagement there, and thus I now cross-post it here…]

Comment: Transitive on faces of a given dimension meaning there are symmetries taking any face of that dimension to any other face of that dimension. Similarly, flag-transitive meaning there are symmetries taking any flag to any other flag.

Comment: Can you give me a reference where I can find the notions? I am not an expert on polytopes. The notion you gave seems to be very dynamical.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to have an [abstract polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_polytope) where the automorphism group acts transitively on the faces of each rank (*fully transitive*) but does not act transitively on flags (not *regular*).

For any flag $\Phi$ and any $j$ let $\Phi_j$ denote the face of rank $j$ in $\Phi$ and let $\Phi^j$ denote the flag adjacent to $\Phi$ which differs only in the rank $j$ face. Call an abstract polytope *chiral* if there are two orbits of flags with $\Phi$ and $\Phi^j$ in different orbits for any $\Phi$ and $j$. By definition chiral abstract polytopes are not regular. However, they are fully transitive. Pick some $j$ and $\Phi$. We will show any face of rank $j$ is in the same orbit as $\Phi_j$. Take any face of rank $j$ and let $\Psi$ be some flag containing this face. Choose $k \neq j$. Then $\Psi$ is in the same orbit as either $\Phi$ or $\Phi^k$ and $\Phi_j = (\Phi^k)_j$. This result holds for other *two-orbit* abstract polytopes also (see Lemma 1.28 of the thesis [Constructions of $k$-orbit polytopes](https://repository.library.northeastern.edu/files/neu:1569/fulltext.pdf) by Helfand).

It remains to see such abstract polytopes exist. Searching the literature will yield several papers on constructing chiral abstract polytopes. One such paper is [A construction of higher rank chiral polytopes](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2009.11.034) by Pellicer which shows chiral abstract polytopes exist in any rank $\geq 3$.

Answer (score 3):

An illustration for the answer by John Machacek:

[image]

Identifying opposite sides of the picture, one gets a 3-polytope with five vertices, ten edges and five square faces. (This is the well known torus map $\{4,4\}_{(1,2)}$.)